# WinCE 6.0 How to move the mouse pointer after OS boots

Tags: c++, windows-ce

As the title says really. I would like to have the mouse pointer moved to a specific x,y location. The default location is centre screen and I would like to have it located bottom right (i.e. just off-screen as a sort of cursor hidden workaround).

I can see there is a MovePointer member function available in the display driver sources e.g. line ~684 in s3c2410x_lcd.cpp (device emulator lcd module) but what I'm missing is the know how about how/where to make a call to this function.

Note that I'm not looking to disable the cursor completely here. If I wanted to do that I know already that I can just set the cursorDisabled property to true. The issue is more that making calls to MovePointer() within the driver don't seem to take affect.

Does anybody have any tips on how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Call the [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms931453.aspx) function.

Linked page is for Windows CE 5.0, but it exists in 6.0 as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know if a call to mouse_event can take place during the OS boot phase i.e in the lcd driver init function for example?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know